# advanced Front end editiing in typo3

Tags: typo3, frontend, backend

I am using extension advanced FE Editing in "typo3" ..

After installation , i can see active editing and deactivate editing ..

but when i try to edit from front-end  ( with log in of admin ) 
i get error message ,

```
  Oops, an error occurred!

    Class TYPO3\CMS\Backend\Sprite\SpriteManager does not have a constructor, so you cannot pass any constructor arguments
```

i write in typoscript like this ,

```
<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/default/TypoScript/setup.ts">

page.config.admPanel = 1
```

or

```
i also tried this

<INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE:fileadmin/default/TypoScript/setup.ts">
 config.admPanel = 1
```

help me , how can i solve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Advanced Frontend Editing extension is not actively maintained at the moment and only compatible up to TYPO3 4.7. There are ongoing discussions about how to proceed with it:

http://forum.typo3.org/index.php/t/201671/

So currently you need to stick to the classic frontend editing in TYPO3 (sysext:feedit) or try out the frontend editing based on Aloha:

http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/aloha

Comment: hey lorenz , thanks...
but what is the solution for frontend editing in current version of typo3 ?? how can we edit our page , irre-element without the use of advanced FEediting extension ?

Comment: Probably not a very constructive comment, but: there are quite some arguments against FE editing. Maybe it would help rethinking if it's really a profit for your editors. On the other hand, http://neos.typo3.org/ will give your editors smooth in-page-editing feel